# masking and mapping aligned 1D arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, mapping, sequence, bioinformatics

I am searching for support in PostgreSQL to process protein sequences for tasks which seem generic or common enough that I suspect that I am not applying the correct Google query terms or defining the problems in the best way.  I am aware of PostBIS and PostBio, but these seem to be more focused on detecting sequence relationships rather than applying them.

Primitive functions that I am initially looking for are along the lines of:

**masking**: given array1 1..n of chars and array2 1..n of (bool equivalents), return array3 which is array1 masked by array2 (either nulling out or splicing out columns in array1 where array2 is 'false').  Alternatively array2 could be start and end positions instead of the full n columns.

**mapping**: given array1 1..n, array2 1..m, and some mapping that tells me e.g. column 10 in array1 is column 28 in array2, return array3 which has the array2 values in the mapped array1 positions.  Again as above, the mapping implementation could be start and end positions of aligned segments instead of full n and m column maps in each direction.

I can envision doing this in database tables with e.g. sequenceID, sequenceIndex and alignMap columns, but it seems like this will generate vast numbers of rows (per sequence position) to index and join across when my software accessing the database usually wants to work on full sequence chunks anyway.

Is there an existing module or approach I should be considering?  An elegant expression with unnest and array_agg (please outline)?  Arrays in PostgreSQL are new to me, but I am learning that processing inside the database is often faster than outside with e.g. perl.  My current PostgreSQL version is 9.1 but expect to move to 9.2 soon.

An application of this would be protein sequence A aligns to structure Z, so where does A's feature 'x' appear on Z?

Answer (score 1):

Some function can be written:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mask(anyarray, boolean[])
RETURNS anyarray AS $$ SELECT ARRAY(SELECT $1[i] 
                          FROM generate_subscripts($1,1) g(i)
                         WHERE $2[i])$$ LANGUAGE sql;


postgres=# SELECT mask(ARRAY['A','B','C','D'], ARRAY[true, false, true, false]);
 mask  
-------
 {A,C}
(1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map(anyarray, int[])
RETURNS anyarray AS $$ SELECT ARRAY(SELECT $1[i]
                          FROM generate_subscripts($1,1) g(i) 
                         ORDER BY $2[i])$$ LANGUAGE sql;


postgres=# SELECT map(ARRAY['A','B','C','D'], ARRAY[4,3,2,1]);
 map    
-----------
 {D,C,B,A}
(1 row)
```

But I afraid so it can be ineffective for longer arrays. Better implementation can be done in prepared 9.4. But for 9.1 and 9.2 only implementation in C can be really effective for long arrays (longer than 1000 fields). But this can be relatively very simple code.

You should to do performance tests.